# linux .so performance degenerate compared to direct compiled executable file

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, inverted-index

I have encountered a problem that puzzled me for a long time. I wonder if anyone could shed any lights on this issue.

I have been writing an inverted index to support text retrieval. I implemented 2 ways to support user query, but the performance differs greatly.

The first way: 
     compile the inverted index with an extra test file which contain a main function that support user query.

file :InvertedIndex.cpp   UserQuery.cpp

compile:

```
     g++ -g -Wall -O3 -fPIC -o textSearch1 InvertedIndex.cpp UserQuery.cpp -I ... -L ...
```

The second way: 
      compile the inverted index as a dynamic shared library, a test file contains main function linked to the dynamic shared library.

file: InvertedIndex.cpp     UserQuery.cpp

compile:

```
     g++ -shared -fPIC -o libInveredIndex.so InvertedIndex.cpp -I ... -L ...
     g++ -Wall -O3 -fPIC -o textSearch2 UserQuery.cpp -I ... -L ... -l InveredIndex
```

I test both textSearch1 and textSearch2 on a pre-built inverted index file, and the query time differs greatly. The inverted index file was loaded by mmap.

For the same query ( more than 2 keywords ), the time costed by textSearch2 is twice as the time costed by textSearch1.

I have tested a lot of queries with more than 2 keywords but the phenomenon repeats.

I could not figure out why. I searched a lot and found nothing.

Please help me if you have any idea.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that you do not need `-fPIC` when compiling the executable, that flag is only needed when compiling `.o` to be used in a shared library.

Answer (score 0):

In your shared shared library compilation line, you do not specify the `-O3` optimisation switch, which is likely to make your library routine less efficient.

In any case, compiling the library separately and then linking may be slower anyway. The compiler is not able to optimise as aggressively as it would if it was compiling the whole thing as a single compilation unit (for example, it may not be able to inline functions - such as library call functions - that it would otherwise)